# Minimize $z=3x_1+2x_2$

Tags: optimization

> Minimize $z=3x_1+2x_2$
>
> s.t
>
> $2x_1+x_2\geq 10$
>
> $-3x_1+2x_2\leq 6$
>
> $x_1+x_2\geq 6$
>
> $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$

The feasible area is : [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%202x%2By%3E%3D10%20and%20-3x%2B2y%3C%3D6%20and%20x%2By%3E%3D6%20and%20x%3E%3D0%20and%20y%3E%3D0%20between%200%20to%2010) how can I find graphically that the answer is $(4,2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3x_1 + 2x_2 = (2x_1 + x_2) + (x_1 + x_2) \ge 10 + 6 = 16.$

Solving the system of linear equations, equality holds at $(4,2).$ The other conditions are easily verified to be true for this point, so the minimum is $16.$

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the minimal value of $k$ such that
$$3x_1+2x_2=k$$
$$\therefore x_2=\frac{k}2-\frac32x_1$$
In order for a solution to exist the line $x_2=\frac{k}2-\frac32x_1$ must intersect the area shown. The value of $k$ can then be reduced which will translate the graph downwards until there is a single intersection with the given area. The value of $k$ when a single intersection occurs is then the minimal value of $3x_1+2x_2$.